# Union several pyproject.toml to one

Tags: pip, python-packaging, python-poetry, requirements.txt

I there a way to union/combine several `pyproject.toml` files to one? Maybe not `pyproject.toml`, but a `poetry.lock` at least. I need to union Poetry dependencies of several projects to one `requirements.txt`, how can I do this right? It is strange that I cannot find any documentation about this basic feature.

Comment: Can you explain more why you have multiple files in the first place?

Comment: @blueteeth Hello! I have several projects with their pyproject.toml files. For docker environment I need to install them separately and it's ok, but for linux server environment it's necessary to have one venv for all projects and this is the reason why I need to combine several pyprojects

Comment: If I were you I would try to export each Poetry's dependencies into a `requirements.txt` file, and then I would try to concatenate all `requirements.txt` file into one. Have you tried this? -- There is quite a high chance of conflicts though.

Comment: @sinoroc Sure, one package can be 1.5.4, another 1.5.3 and both of them are valid for conditions but there will be conflict. I hope that there is easy right way using some poetry command. Can I just activate one poetry and than add another poetry to it?

Comment: You could try to add all your Poetry-managed projects as dependencies of one Poetry project, let Poetry generate a `poetry.lock`, and then generate a `requirements.txt` out of this.

Answer (score 0):

After all I decided to write a script to union several toml files into one and manually resolve some conflicts on existence

link: https://github.com/PasaOpasen/toml-union