Generate dependency files Gitlab
I have two python packages in  two different Gitlab projects, each having  a .toml dependency file. I have another project that is used to create a docker container that is to be used for running tests on these packages. Currently, I manually create a dependency file combining all dependencies to be installed on the container.
I’m wondering if this process can be done automatically such that it automatically manages and groups dependencies? I tried Renovate but it it did not help.

This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76346767/union-several-pyproject-toml-to-one
